# Laravel Nova - Create many objects with a single form submission

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a section in my Laravel Nova from where I can create a schedule for classes. In the front-end, my teachers can easily create many classes from a single form by defining a repeat_till and repeat_frequency fields. How can I go about achieving the same results in Laravel Nova?

My own controller has the following code:

```
if($data['repeat'] && $data['repeat_till']) {
    $next_date = Carbon::parse($data['date']);
    $end_date = Carbon::parse($data['repeat_till']);
                
    while($next_date <= $end_date) {
        $dates[] = $next_date->format('Y-m-d');   
        $next_date = $next_date->addDays($data['repeat']);
    }
 } else {
    $dates[] = $data['date'];
 }

...

$parent = null;

foreach($dates as $date) {
    $schedule = Schedule::create([
        ...
        'date' => $date,
        'parent_id' => ($parent ? $parent->id : null),
        ...
    ]);

    if(!$parent) {
        $parent = $schedule;
    }
}
```

I've looked at the possibility of using Observers for this and so far that seems like the only viable option. However, for that I will need to have access to the repeat(repeat_frequency) and repeat_till values, which are not part of the Schedule model. How can I go about accessing these values in the created method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by overriding the save function inside your model
public function save(array $options = array())

and since you don't have access to the repeat_frequency and repeat_till values inside your observer, i'm guessing these aren't database fields.. so what i recommend is unsetting these variables before saving the model.. EX:

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{

    if($this->exists == false)
    {
        //means you're creating a model
        

        //this is where you write your code
        foreach($dates as $date) {
        $schedule = Schedule::create([
            ...
            'date' => $date,
            'parent_id' => ($parent ? $parent->id : null),
            ...
            ]);

        }


    }
    else
    {
        //updating a model
    }

    //you need to comment this since you're creating the schedules in a different way
    //parent::save($options);
}
```